# Failed to run python manage.py migrate command on AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance manually

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have created the project with command

```
:: eb create --database.engine postgres --region ap-southeast-1.
```

It shows that my deployment is successful.
Also when I run command `:: eb open`, it successfully open my project website.

Also when I checked eb-activity logs on my instance at /var/log/eb-activity.log, it also shows migration successful when I deployed my project.

But When I tried to run `$ python manage.py migrate`  manually on Elastic Beanstalk instance it gives error,

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Also when I tried to create a user manually on python manage.py shell. It again gives error,

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I want to access postgres database on elastikbeanstalk instance and want to use commands
`$ python manage.py migrate`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you need to correct the database host setting

Comment: I have added database setting as below  if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }     and my migration was successful during deployment.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working because your application was trying to connect to localhost for the database. Can you check if RDS_DB_NAME is set as the environment variable? Migrations successful?

Comment: Yes it is set. Here is the name as =>  export RDS_DB_NAME="mydbname"

Comment: could you also check the value of 'RDS_HOSTNAME and RDS_PORT?

Comment: Here is the migration complete partial log  => 
  Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
  Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK

Comment: export RDS_PORT="5432"  && export RDS_HOSTNAME="xxxxxxxxxxxx.cnxpqbflfonl.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com"

Comment: If this is the case then there would not be an error. Django is looking for the db on localhost not on RDS_HOSTNAME. Try reseting it and running the migrations again